# Laravel 10 Observer attribute not working

Tags: php, laravel-10, observers

I have a ProductPrice Model which I register an observer attribute with ObservedBy on as follows

```
#[ObservedBy([ProductPriceObserver::class])]
class ProductPrice extends Model
{
    use HasFactory, HasUlids;

    protected $fillable = ['price', 'is_current', 'product_id'];

}
```

This doesn't fire the observer at all.

manually registering the observer in the boot method of EventServiceProvider works

```
    public function boot(): void
    {
        ProductPrice::observe(ProductPriceObserver::class);

    }
```

I am very keen on getting the above to work as it is much more neater
reference [here](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent#observers)

Comment: That feature is available from Laravel 10.44

Comment: That answers it. I'm on 10.40.0. Thanks